# Is there a way to keep a frequency band while attenuating the rest?

Tags: python, librosa

Say I have an audio track with a variety of sounds ranging from low frequencies up to 20k. Is there a way I can filter away everything outside a given band and play back the result?

Comment: Is this python specific? In general you could use a band-pass filter...

Comment: Yes, Python specific. I'm leaning towards computing a complex spectrogram, doing the filtering there, and coming back to the time domain. It's not clear that's the most efficient way with librosa though.

Comment: I don't know `librosa`, but I know that `scipy` can do the job. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) in the filtering section.